# Why does PHP have two password hashing functions?

Tags: php, passwords

I've been doing some reading on password hashing lately, and I've found that PHP has two password hashing functions: [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

`crypt()` looks more versatile and configurable and is what I personally use, but I've read that `password_hash()` is better even though it only takes two arguments and only uses one algorithm.

Can someone please inform me of any major differences between these two functions, or if one is more secure than the other when used correctly? If there's no real difference, then can someone explain to me why there are two functions that appear to do the same thing, only one is better at it?

Comment: `password_hash` should be your default option if you're on PHP 5.5+.

Comment: `crypt()` uses a weak hashing algorithm and allows you to choose a bad salt. `password_hash()` uses a strong password hashing algorithm and generates a strong random salt unless you provide your own.

Comment: You should concentrate and use `password_hash` until you learn otherwise. Right now there is not much for you to decide, take `password_hash` and done. Even if you're not on PHP 5.5 you find the function as PHP code so you can use it as well in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Can't you generate a random salt using crypt? Can't you use blowfish with crypt? Why use `password_hash`?

Comment: @Mister Melancholy: Because it's better for you. You can do a lot, for example go out, grab a car and paint it blue. `password_hash` will still do what you're looking for. Regardless with which words you throw around, be it salt, pepper, blowfish or bluetooth.

Comment: How is it better for me? I can use the `crypt` function and have it do exactly what the `password_hash` function does and more, can I not? @hakre

Comment: @hakre: What do you mean by Bcrypt uses blowfish internally, but crypt can't use Bcrypt? Isn't Bcrypt a function/object? Why is using Bcrypt from `password_hash` better than using `crypt` with blowfish? Don't they both use blowfish?

Comment: So when you hash the same string with the same algorithm, same salts, and same everything else, you get different hashes? @hakre

Comment: @Blender that is not true at all. `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` is for bcrypt hashes. In fact, password_hash() even uses crypt to hash passwords ([see here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php))

Comment: @Mike: Whoops, sorry. It looks like you're right.

Comment: @Mister Melancholy: You have no clue what you're talking about which I say is no problem as long as you first of all accept to start with using the `password_hash` function and not bother much about the why. Then, with some more time and peace of mind, the much more complicated things can be clarified for you if you actually start reading about the topic. It's complicated, there is a lot of literature, and asking here on Stackoverflow doesn't work out well with your question, because I bet nobody voluntarily will place you a book as an answer.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy: No with the same and whaterver you get the same. However the problem is that you yet do not understand that all. But that is fine. There is no problem with that. As long as you accept for the moment to take `password_hash` and then after you did that, you have more peace of mind to actually confront yourself with all the open ends which you establish here as quick questions you so much want to get an answer but I don't give it to you because right now you're in constant questioning mode and you're actually not interested to read about the things so it's a bit of a hard work.

Comment: @hakre: I'm not looking for a book, I'm looking for something beyond "use `password_hash` because you just should" and why it isn't the same as `crypt`.

Comment: ... to tell you about all this because to do it right it would require a book and as I already wrote in my last comment that is not so fitting for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy: Even if it would be the same as crpyt, so what?

Comment: @harke: That's exactly what I'm asking. If it's exactly the same as `crypt`, why not just use `crypt`?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy: Because for the case you ask something like that, the function `password_hash` has been created because using `crypt` is too complicated for you (there are some more reasons, but that pretty much nails it). And with complicated I don't mean you are personally not able to understand that, it's just that you wonder right now.

Comment: But as you write you actually use crypt, it's true the other way round as well: As you use `crypt` you don't need to worry about `password_hash` because you know what you do. `password_hash` has been introduced for those who don't know what to do, they should use `password_hash` then. Sounds fair?

Comment: @harke: Yes. That sounds much more understandable. THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main differences between plain `crypt` and `password_hash`. It is also worth mentioning that `password_hash` uses `crypt` in its implementation, so we're basically comparing a car motor (crypt) to an entire car (password_hash) here.

The first difference between the two would therefore be that `crypt` is ONLY for calculating the hash. You have to do everything else on your own. There are three things that you will have to implement on  your own:

- Generating a salt
- Verifying the hash
- Determine whether you need to re-hash (optional, but recommended)

With `password_hash`, unless you specify a salt (which you shouldn't do unless you really know what you're doing), it will generate the most secure available salt on your OS available. Salt generation is probably the most complicated part and the part that can most easily be done wrong without you even knowing you're doing it wrong. `crypt` is *needed* for verifying the hash, but again, you have to make your own implementation. Even the [man page on php.net](http://www.php.net/crypt#example-4780) gets it wrong. Compare that to [password_verify()](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) and you will see it's not just a simple `==` that should be done for hash verification.

Secondly, crypt allows you to create bad hashes using obsolete hash types. As of the time of writing, `password_hash` only uses bcrypt, however using Using `password_hash` with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` will always guarantee you will be hashing using the strongest recommended and available hash. `crypt`, in providing flexibility, also allows the programmer more room to make mistakes in choosing the wrong hash type and unless you constantly monitor security warnings, you may not even know that what you are doing is wrong or that (perhaps) a new and stronger hashing algorithm has been implemented in PHP. `password_hash` in that sense will be future-proof unless you force it not to be. It wouldn't surprise me that in the next few years when scrypt is built into PHP, it will be made the new default algorithm in `password_hash` as well.

So in summary, always use password_hash(). And if you don't have php >= 5.5 download [Ircmaxell's compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I think I get it; `crypt` is like a framework for password hashing, and `password_hash` is a "plug-and-play" version that the smart people can update it and keep as secure as possible without anybody else having to worry about it. I see a lot of potential problems down the road, but the ones I can think of are significantly better problems to have than insecure hashes.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy well keep in mind that crypt was implemented way before password_hash was. As caskey's answer says, password_hash was created because people didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: Yeah. I think I'm just being stubborn at this point. I see why the function exists and am very glad that progress is being made to make security easier to implement. You did a spectacular job answering my question, and I appreciate all of the time and effort you put into your answer.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy - There are not so much problems as you may think. The generated hash-values contain the used algorithm, the salt and the cost factor, that's why the function `password_verify()` can and will be backwards compatible. It is possible to verify differently generated hashes. Another thing: `crypt()` does not only hash passwords, hashes can be used also for other things, but not every hash algorithm (SHA* for example) should be used for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It provides access to the crypt(3) function.  This is a traditional function that pre-dates PHP by a few decades.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)

It operates in several modes and would generally be used to interface with password data shared among other systems.

The password_hash function exists because properly using the bare crypt(3) function is fraught with peril.

Comment: So you mean that the `password_hash` function was made because developers don't know how to use `crypt` properly?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Yes. Some more rationale for password_hash is given at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash